# Optic from map to its association pairs

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, haskell-optics

I need a `Fold (Map k v) (k, v)` optic. Is there a way to obtain it with the "optics" library? If not, is there one with "lens"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In either `optics` or `lens`, you should be able to write:

```
pairs :: Fold (Map k v) (k, v)
pairs = folding Map.toList
```

Generally speaking `folding` takes any function that produces a foldable result (in this case, a list of key-value pairs) and creates a fold over those elements.